# Facebook buttonI am using a firebaseUI multiple login all buttons are generating except Facebook Builder().build() How to inflate that button

Tags: android, android-studio, firebaseui

I am using a firebaseUI multiple login all buttons are generating except Facebook Builder().build()

How to inflate that button

Answer (score 0):

add the list of supported providers as follows :

```
 List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());
```

and then you create the sign in intent :

```
   Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build();
```

call startActivityForResult() with 'intent'

Edit :

You need to add the following dependencies to your app level gradle file :

```
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.1'
```

Note that you don't need the firebase auth dependency because it's included in the firebase-ui dependency

Comment: I dont undertand the logic

Comment: showing error `   Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
                .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(
                                        "https://example.com/terms.html",
                                "https://example.com/privacy.html")
                .build();

        //startActivityForResult(intent);
        //showSignInOptions();

        startActivityForResult(intent,MY_REQUEST_CODE);`

Comment: i am not able to upload code over here can you please share your email id so that i can send you the code

Comment: showing error means when i add FacebookBuilder().build() it stops the app without this line app works fine

Comment: make sure you have the facebook dependency

Comment: i have already these dependencies   //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'

    //Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.1'

Comment: can you please provide the code for all your dependencies as well as the sign in intent as an edit to the original question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212292/discussion-between-anurag-tiwari-and-ahmed-osama).

Comment: please send your email id

Comment: sir i add all code over here this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373084/i-am-using-firebase-ui-login-into-my-app-but-when-i-use-facebook-builder-it-stop