# I am using firebase UI login into my app but when i use Facebook builder it stops the app how to inflate that button..?

Tags: java, android, firebaseui

i am enclosing the code of the Java file, dependency file and Manifestfile

i declared outside

```
 private static final int MY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build());
```

after this i mentioned this

```
 Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .setLogo(R.drawable.logo)
                .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls(
                                        "https://example.com/terms.html",
                                "https://example.com/privacy.html")
                .build();
```

and the last i mention the startActivity

```
startActivityForResult(intent,MY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

now this is my Dependencies File

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'  //1.0.2
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'

    //Facebook
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    //Cardview and Material
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' //1.1.0

    //button
    implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
}
```

after this it is my Manifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Geo_Activity"/>
        <activity android:name=".Profile" />
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

now the problem is that when I add the Facebuilder().build() line into my array list the app is crashed

this is the output screen
[image: Output]

Comment: can you include the crash error statement

Answer (score 1):

Change your dependencies to :

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'  //1.0.2
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

//Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.1'

//Facebook

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.1'



testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
//Cardview and Material
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' //1.1.0

//button
implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Edit :

Add these two strng resources to your strngs :

```
    <string name="facebook_application_id" translatable="false">APP_ID</string>
<!-- Facebook Application ID, prefixed by 'fb'. Enables Chrome Custom tabs. -->
<string name="facebook_login_protocol_scheme" translatable="false">fbAPP_ID</string>
```

If you run the app, It will work now, but clicking the facebook button won't get the user authenticated until you get the app id and scheme

To get the app id, log into your facebook account, visit the developers page https://developers.facebook.com/
Create an app there, then add the 'facebook login' and then follow the instructions given. You will find your app id in the top of the page of your facebook app

Just two notes :

- You  need copy the 'OAuth Redirect URI' from the firebase console page(the link given when enabling facebook authentication) to the settings of your facebook app
- You will need the 'Key hash' which you can be obtained as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25524657/9006761
  You will then copy it to your facebook app settings

Edit :
Scheme is just app id prefixed by 'fb'

Comment: i got this error.................>>>>java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demotask/com.example.demotask.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Facebook provider unconfigured. Make sure to add a `facebook_application_id` string. See the docs for more info: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#facebook

Comment: Come on man ! why didn't you post that earlier ?!! I will edit the answer

Comment: sorry for that pardon me

Comment: added strings into strings.xml  and added Oauth into facebook settings but again it is not working

Comment: add the strings again, I changed scheme string to be the app id prefixed by 'fb'

Comment: Thank you So so much for helping me.

Comment: Look documentation here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#facebook

Comment: Sir i want to add Text on the above of the Logo in the photo include by me

Comment: You need to define your custom layout as described here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md#custom-layout

Comment: please sir help me out in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386532/i-am-using-firebaseui-multiple-login-method-but-how-to-give-permissions-to-every