# I am using FirebaseUi multiple login method but how to give permissions to everybody to login into the app..?

Tags: android, firebaseui, facebook-oauth

i am using **FirebaseUI** multiple login and i registered the app to the **facebook for developers** where i am the Administrator of that app only i can login into the app but when same app launch in my friend's mobile it says:

**App not Setup: This App is still in development mode,and you don't have access to it. 
Switch to a registered test user or ask admin for permissions.**

but i want whenever a new person open my app and start login with facebook it will ask his Username and password everytime

[image: here it is the snip of error]

and here it is facebook App dashboard image

[image]

it is showing this kind of message when i toggle the button **In Development**

[image]

Comment: @ahmed osama please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

Go to the facebook developers page, select your app
You will find a switch on top 'In development', You need toggle it, It might ask you to provide a contact email and privacy policy, just set them in the setting of the app

Comment: It is asking for privacy policy URL for app Live...how can i publish own privacy policy

Comment: Can i create a HTML page which includes privacy policy of app and i am thinking to upload that page on free web hosting site... Can i do that...is it work..??

Comment: i created a website https://demotaskapp.000webhostapp.com/ where i put index.html in which i paste all privacy text and publish it but again facebook sharing debugger showing  The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Comment: i am enclosing the message above(photo) given after whenever i uploaded the privacy policy file into settings